# Pandas for partially duplicate rows, keep row and replace data with minimum or maximum value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is what my initial dataframe looks like:

```
pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','b','c'],
             'b': [1,2,3,4],
             'c': [2,3,4,1],'d':[1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4]})
```

```
    a   b   c   d

0   a   1   2   1.1

1   b   2   3   1.2

2   b   3   4   1.3

3   c   4   1   1.4
```

For the duplicate values in column **a**,   I want to keep the minimum value for column **b** and the maximum value for column **c**

The output should be like this:

```
    a   b   c   d

0   a   1   2   1.1

1   b   2   4   1.2

2   b   2   4   1.3

3   c   4   1   1.4
```

Is there a pandas function that does that?
I tried looking into

```
pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates
pandas.DataFrame.duplicated
```

However, I didn't find anything that will work for my use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `min` and `max` what return same values for unique groups:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['a','b','b','c'],
             'b': [1,2,3,4],
             'c': [2,3,4,1],'d':[1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4]})

df['b'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].transform('min')
df['c'] = df.groupby('a')['c'].transform('max')
print (df)
   a  b  c    d
0  a  1  2  1.1
1  b  2  4  1.2
2  b  2  4  1.3
3  c  4  1  1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work:

```
df2=df.groupby('a').agg({'b':'min', 'c':'max'})
result=df2.merge(df, on='a')[['a', 'b_x', 'c_x', 'd']]
result.columns=df.columns

>>> print(result)
   a  b  c    d
0  a  1  2  1.1
1  b  2  4  1.2
2  b  2  4  1.3
3  c  4  1  1.4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
m=df.a.duplicated(False)#boolean select all duplicated in column a
df.loc[m,['b','c']]=df.loc[m,'b'].min(),df.loc[m,'c'].max()#mask columns b and c and assign min and max as per condition
print(df)



  a  b  c    d
0  a  1  2  1.1
1  b  2  4  1.2
2  b  2  4  1.3
3  c  4  1  1.4
```